# SOLRCloud 7.3.1: CDCR issues

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We have the following environment setup: 
    SOLRCloud 
    SOLR Version: 7.3.1 
    9 Nodes per DC 
    2 DCs 
    2 Separate ZK ensemble (one for each SOLR DC) 
    CDCR bidirectional enabled. 
    2 Collections. 
    3 shards per collection, 3 replication factors. 
    Basic auth enabled. (Aware of CDCR basic auth issues, so added other 
    DC_nodes information as part of live_nodes. 
    ZK ACL enabled. 
    Solr Node JVM heap=64 GB with G1GC enabled and tuned.

```
######################### 
solrConfig settings for CDCR 

 <lst name="replicator"> 
    <str name="threadPoolSize">8</str> 
    <str name="schedule">1000</str> 
    <str name="batchSize">512</str> 
  </lst> 

  <lst name="updateLogSynchronizer"> 
    <str name="schedule">1000</str> 
    </lst> 

######################### 

-Dsolr.autoCommit.maxTime=60000 -Dsolr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime=1000 

######################### 

Now, we are seeing the following issues: 

1. Data inserted into one DC not forwarding into other DC after insert 
without any hard commit. 
2. Data inserted into one DC not forwarding into other DC after insert with 
hard commit. Verified with /get as well. 
3. After doing a hard commit on target DC and RELOAD, data started showing 
up. But solr numfound is not matching across DCs. 

Errors: 
Each individual shards leader queueSize was either -1 or 0. And showing 
bad_request 

8983/solr/collection_name_shard2_replica_n6/cdcr?action=QUEUES 

{ 
  "responseHeader":{ 
    "status":0, 
    "QTime":1}, 
  "queues":[ 
    "abc.com:2181,abc1.com:2181,abc2.com:2181",[ 
      "collection_name",[ 
        "queueSize",0, 
        "lastTimestamp","2018-08-01T17:21:29.990Z"]]], 
  "tlogTotalSize":16545113, 
  "tlogTotalCount":5, 
  "updateLogSynchronizer":"stopped"} 



ERROR from log: 


INFO  - 2018-07-31 17:54:46.722; [   ] 
org.apache.solr.handler.CdcrReplicatorManager$BootstrapStatusRunnable; CDCR 
bootstrap successful in 5 seconds 
INFO  - 2018-07-31 17:54:46.889; [   ] 
org.apache.solr.handler.CdcrReplicatorManager$BootstrapStatusRunnable; 
Create new update log reader for target collection_name with checkpoint 
1607545724212346885 @ collection_name:shard2 
ER 
ERROR - 2018-07-31 17:54:47.052; [   ] 
org.apache.solr.handler.CdcrReplicatorManager$BootstrapStatusRunnable; 
Unable to bootstrap the target collection collection_name shard: shard2 


WARN : [c:collection_name s:shard2 r:core_node11 
x:collection_name_shard2_replica_n8] 
org.apache.solr.handler.CdcrRequestHandler; The log reader for target 
collection collection_name is not initialised @ collection_name:shard2 

So wondering how do we proceed further. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: yes..Upto Some extent.